# Moblie Status Indicator For Bot

Tags: javascript, python, discord

So according to [someone on Github](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/1352#issuecomment-640091020) you can make your Bot appear online on Mobile Client :

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js')
    const Client = new Discord.Client()
    const Constants = require('discord.js/src/util/Constants.js')
    Constants.DefaultOptions.ws.properties.$browser = `Discord iOS`
    Client.on("ready", () => {
      console.log("Loading status..")
      Client.user.setActivity(`!help for commands`, { type: 3, browser: "DISCORD IOS"  });
    });
```

the code is working and bot came online with a phone status indicator, did a little search and found the same code from `constants.js` in a file named `gateway.py` from discord.py library : [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYHCn.png)

I know this is a dumb question to ask but i'd appreciate if anyone can actually help me out with this.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly the bot is supposed to do, what it does correctly, and what it does not do? I'd start by changing the title to be phrased as a question.

Answer (score 1):

Change line 370 in gateway.py

```
async def identify(self):
    """Sends the IDENTIFY packet."""
    payload = {
        'op': self.IDENTIFY,
        'd': {
            'token': self.token,
            'properties': {
                '$os': sys.platform,
                '$browser': 'Discord iOS', #change this from discord.py to Discord iOS
                '$device': 'discord.py',
                '$referrer': '',
                '$referring_domain': ''
            },
            'compress': True,
            'large_threshold': 250,
            'guild_subscriptions': self._connection.guild_subscriptions,
            'v': 3
        }
    }
```

Comment: another note to remember is you have to have your bot as online, idle dnd and offline will not show as mobile from what I have tested. A few people claim its against tos but I have no idea why it would be and I have not see discord explicitly say it is

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the JS code you sent, the program requires a specific file from the library, applies a few changes to it, and then connects as a mobile user.

If you wanted to perform the same trick using discord.py, I'd suggest you to dig a little bit inside the library (you could compare with discord.js, I'm sure this part should be quite similar) and then come up with your own, working mobile connection system for python !